# push jar file to my java heroku app using CLI

Tags: heroku, jar, command-line-interface

I am running a javascript app in heroku (scoold) and have been told by the developer that there is a new jar file to upload. I Downloaded the heroku cli  and jar file and ran the following commands as instructed:

```
heroku plugins:install java
heroku deploy:jar scoold-x.y.z.jar --app myscooldapp
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    C:\Sites>heroku deploy:jar scoold-pro-1.37.1.jar --app nocodeflow
Uploading scoold-pro-1.37.1.jar
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn java',
  path: 'java',
  spawnargs: [
    '-Dheroku.appName=nocodeflow',
    '-Xmx1g',
    '-Dheroku.jarFile=scoold-pro-1.37.1.jar',
    '-Dheroku.jarOpts=',
    '-cp',
    'C:\\Users\\Artwe\\AppData\\Local\\heroku\\node_modules\\@heroku-cli\\plugin-java\\lib\\heroku-deploy-complete.jar',
    'com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployJar'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a ticket on the Heroku support center, because I had the same problem.
I want to deploy a simple war and normally I don't need any Node.js ...